# R lm using subset of my data frame with c(index)

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression, lm

I have a large data frame. The first n columns represent my dependent variables, the remaining m=(N-n) columns represent my explanatory variables.

I need to do a variable selection, i.e., I want to run a linear model with one of my dependent variables against a selection of explanatory variables.

I use the following code, but it does not work.

```
structure(list(y1 = c(-0.159526983540257, 2.16892194367082, 0.695539528415267, 
-0.841375527728487, 0.146186718603554), y2 = c(0.843930369507526, 
1.15189158283099, -0.162651238219114, 0.384543148695671, -0.768095169822086
), y3 = c(0.676606087565373, -1.54403120779262, 0.309217049561983, 
-1.35994467980478, 0.025666048887934), x1 = c(-0.462318888988991, 
0.637219370641707, 0.169306615605319, 0.773825637643689, -1.80512938432685
), x2 = c(0.420644990269304, 0.168496378157891, -0.288787457624397, 
-1.8207116669123, -1.04563859296061), x3 = c(0.529585006756937, 
-0.69696010268217, 0.72760512189806, 1.27475852051601, 0.0547933726620265
), x4 = c(0.995548762574541, -1.42396489630791, 1.34343306027338, 
1.14879495559021, 1.11600859581743), x5 = c(-0.989878720668274, 
-0.823824983427361, -1.58910626627862, -0.987929834373281, -1.75551410908407
), x6 = c(-0.206995723222616, -0.712762437418153, -0.516370544799284, 
0.124635650806358, 1.08149368199072), x7 = c(-0.409575294823497, 
1.5077513417679, -1.17700768734441, -0.159607245758965, 1.11768048557717
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))   

    index=c(5,8,9)

    model = lm(df[,1] ~ df[,c(index)])
```

Is it possible to subset the data frame in a similar way? I really want to avoid column names, since I may run several different models.

Edit: the length of c(index) may vary each time.

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag page so that others can easily run the code using copy and paste into their R session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reformulate :

with `index_y` the index of your y variable of interest in your dataframe `df`

```
model=lm(reformulate(colnames(df)[index],response=colnames(df)[index_y]),df)
```

Comment: Can I use response=colnames(df[,index_y])?

Comment: I updated my answer to fit this specific question

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
# Generating data.
n = 1000 # Use n for denoting number of observations, for consistency reasons!
k = 20 # k is used for independent/explanatory variables (also p often)!

set.seed(1986)

X = matrix(rnorm(n * k), ncol = k)
y = runif(n)

df = data.frame(y, X)
head(df)

# Fitting model on a subset of explanatory variables.
index = 4:10
model = lm(y ~ ., data = df[, index])
summary(model)
```

First of all, let me advice you about notation: `n` is generally used to denote the number of observations, i.e., the number of rows (not columns), while `k` or `p` are used for explanatory variables. Moreover, explantory and independent variables are the same thing - so maybe you meant that you *want to run a linear model with one of my **dependent** variables against a selection of explanatory variables*.

Going back to your question, I suggest to rely on the optional parameter `data` in the `lm()` function to pass only the data you actually want to use. In this way, you can use the formula `y ~ .`, which reads as *regress `y` on all the other variables you find in the `data` I pass in*.

As final warning, I set `index = 4:10`. Notice that I am not using explanatory/independent variables from the fourth to the tenth, but from the third to the ninth, as the first column of `data` is `y`, i.e., the dependent variable (which you have to always include in `data`).

**EDIT**

I see you provided some data to work with. Here how to adapt the code:

```
# Fitting model on a subset of explanatory variables.
index=c(5,8,9)
model = lm(y1 ~ ., data = df[, c(1, index)]) # HERE I AM ADDING THE FIRST COLUMN!
summary(model)
```

Basically, either your `index` includes the column with the dependent variable (`y1` in my case), or you add it in the optional parameter `data` (as I did in the example).

Comment: This works, of course. However, it relies on naming the desired independent variable as y, which I want to avoid. As I mentioned, I have multiple independent variables, so naming them y can be confusing later.

Comment: Again, `y` is the **dependent** variable (it depends on the **independent** variables). Moreover, in your example code you subset `df[, y1`], that is, actually using the name of the desired dependent variable. I can adapt the code to pass a column name, but still you would need to know the name or the location of your desired `y` variable - R cannot know which variable must be explained if you do not gve that information.